# Панель с настройками

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать панель с сохранением настроек для программы, т.е сейчас в программе IP-адрес вбивается руками через код, но нужно что бы была кнопка с настройками где будут все IP-адреса для изменения и возможность сохранения изменения, как это можно реализовать?

Предположительно можно использовать XML файл в него записать IP в нужную строку и опять же возникает вопрос как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про App.Config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы предложил использовать файл конфигурации App.Config. Подробно о том как это сделать указано по этой ссылке https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms184658.aspx.

А для работы с ним использовать класс Configuration, который позволяет программно работать с файлом конфигурации.

Следуйте примеру из этой статьи (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.configuration.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx).

Дополнительную информацию можно найти по следующим ссылкам:

[Настройка приложений с использованием файлов конфигурации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1xtk877y.aspx)

[Строки соединения и файлы конфигурации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пример чтения значения из файла конфигурации:

```
var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]
               .ToString();
```

**UPD:**

Конфигурационный файл
(его нужно положить в ту же папку где лежит .exe файл Вашего приложения и назвать его так же, но с расширением .config.

Если Ваше приложение называется **testapp.exe**, то файл конфигурации должен называться **testapp.exe.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <add key="HostName" value="DESKTOP-TBOUSCL" />
    <add key="IPAddress" value="172.21.29.29" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Пример работы с файлом конфигурации

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GetIPandSaveToConfig
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strHostName = string.Empty;
            strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            textBox1.Text = strHostName;

            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

            foreach (IPAddress ip in ipEntry.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = ip.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Configuration config =     ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);

            //HostName
            if (textBox1.Text == null)
                config.AppSettings.Settings["HostName"].Value = "";
            else
                config.AppSettings.Settings["HostName"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

            //IPAddress
            if (richTextBox1.Text == null)
                config.AppSettings.Settings["IPAddress"].Value = "";
            else
                config.AppSettings.Settings["IPAddress"].Value = richTextBox1.Text;

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            //HostName
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"] != "")
                textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];

            //IPAddress
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPAddress"] != "")
                richTextBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPAddress"];
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.
Не забудьте в References подключить System.configuration

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2:**

Вот ссылка на готовый проект https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JvVf/mEe6MJ3qX

Comment: Статья полезна, но вот я не нашёл как конкретно выгрузить в TextBox ip и как заставить получить его здесь "Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("172.30.224.60");
                PingReply reply;"

Comment: Правильно я понял, что Вам нужно определить текущий IP-адрес сетевого интерфеса, присвоить его в TextBox и записать в файл конфигурации?

Comment: У меня есть ПО она подключается по IP, то что я написал выше это проверка связи. Но бывают случаи когда технику переносят и ПО перестаёт подключаться так как сменился IP то опять нужно залазить в код, а менять его парой нет времени по этому я и хочу сделать настройки что бы каждый у кого есть ПО мог поменять IP

Comment: @Павел: Хранение данных и показ UI — две несвязанные вещи. Если хотите, чтобы вам разжевали, как показать значение в текстбоксе, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. Ответил насколько смог понять Ваш вопрос. Если что-то нужно уточнить - скажите.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Так суть понятна, единственное не понял как это всё сохранить в конфиг файл

Comment: Приведенный мною пример и считывает и сохраняет в конфиг файл.
Вот эта строка кода сохраняет config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

Comment: Добавил ссылку на готовый проект.
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6h6w/rDJS5UHev